# Wrong SONAR error "concat with +=" for line with conditional assignment

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar v.2.11 is complaining with a Major warning: `Use String Buffer For String Appends` for the following line:

```
 hidden = Format.isEmpty(hidden) ? fieldname : hidden;
```

Does anyone know why this could happen? It seems to be wrong as no concatenation is taking place.

- Is it a bug?
- A pattern/rule that confuses conditional assignment?
- Or some kind of caching issue that never re-analyzed a line that changed?

[image]

We are currently running **Sonar v.2.11**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of SonarQube you're running, and presumably the code analyzer as well, is ~5.5 years old. There have been vast improvements in both in the last half decade.

You are extremely unlikely to get a direct answer to your question because so few people have *current* experience on the versions you're using.

I know this isn't the answer you *want* but your best course is to upgrade. Stat!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will pass this information up the chain!